# Whats wrong in my pagination code?

Tags: php, forms, pagination

Below is a code for pagination of search results page. The results for first page appear fine but the next pages are blank not even navigation links appear. However rest of `html` is there just the results are missing. The same pagination code works fine on other pages where pagination is based on some rigid values e.g `WHERE category='Health'` but here I am paginating on the basis of search query submitted in a form `WHERE title LIKE '%".$searchword."%'`. May be this is the issue?

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" class="searchin" name="keyword" placeholder="Enter keyword ..."/>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
$searchword = $_POST['keyword'];
$searchword = filter_var($searchword, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 if( $searchword == "" ) {
 $er = 'Please enter a query to search';
 }
 else{

$search=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE :title");
$search->execute(array(':title'=>'%".$searchword."%'));
$total=$search->rowCount();  
// How many items to list per page
$limit = 10;
// How many pages will there be
$pages = ceil($total / $limit);
// What page are we currently on?
$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
    'options' => array(
        'default'   => 1,
        'min_range' => 1,
    ),
)));
// Calculate the offset for the query
$offset = ($page - 1)  * $limit;
// Some information to display to the user
$start = $offset + 1;
$end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);
// The "back" link
$prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a href="?page=1" title="First page" class="pagin">&laquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Previous page" class="pagin">&lsaquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span>';
// The "forward" link
$nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '" title="Next page" class="pagin">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . $pages . '" title="Last page" class="pagin">&raquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>';
// Prepare the paged query
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE :title ORDER BY posts_id DESC LIMIT
        :limi
    OFFSET
        :offset");
$stmt->bindValue(':title', '%'.$searchword.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':limi', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
 if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    // Define how we want to fetch the results
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $iterator = new IteratorIterator($stmt);

    // Display the results
    foreach ($iterator as $row) {
         echo "<div><h2><a href='post.php?postId=" . $row['posts_id'] . "'>".$row['title']."</a></h2></div>";
     }
   } else {
    echo "<center><h2>No matches for ".$searchword.".</h2></center>";
   }
   if ($search->rowCount() > 10) {
   echo '<center><div class="paginate">', $prevlink,  $nextlink, '</div></center>'; 
  }
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Well... you're not passing the `$searchword` along in the URL, are you?!

Comment: @deceze tried passing `$searchword` $nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '&keyword='.$searchword.'" title="Next page" class="pagin">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . $pages . '" title="Last page" class="pagin">&raquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>'; but didn't work.